# Gmail API - 429 rateLimitExceeded with a single request

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, quota

I was writing a node application that uses the gmail API when I noticed this error. My understanding of the error is that there are too many concurrent requests. It seems to be prompting me to wait 15 minutes and try again.  After the waiting period, I tried to poke the API with the gui over at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#response, but the same error appears (with the time incremental 15 minutes). I've looked at my quota usage on the API site in the developer console, but there's no activity other than the errors. Does anyone know why this might be? I'd be extremely appreciative.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
   "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",
    "message": "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2016-07-11T23:51:49.309Z"
   }
  ],
  "code": 429,
  "message": "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2016-07-11T23:51:49.309Z"
 }
}
```

Comment: you need to post your code

Comment: Never mind, it seems to have resolved itself.

Answer (score 1):

The Gmail API is subject to a daily usage limit that applies to all requests made from your application, as well as per-user rate limits.

- Daily Usage  1,000,000,000 quota units per day Per User Rate
  Limit
- 250 quota units per user per second, moving average (allows
  short bursts)

Exceeding a rate limit will cause an HTTP 403 or HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response and your app should respond by retrying with exponential backoff.

> Exponential backoff is a standard error handling strategy for network
>   applications in which the client periodically retries a failed request
>   over an increasing amount of time. If a high volume of requests or
>   heavy network traffic causes the server to return errors, exponential
>   backoff may be a good strategy for handling those errors. Conversely,
>   it is not a relevant strategy for dealing with errors unrelated to
>   rate-limiting, network volume or response times, such as invalid
>   authorization credentials or file not found errors.
>
> Used properly, exponential backoff increases the efficiency of
>   bandwidth usage, reduces the number of requests required to get a
>   successful response, and maximizes the throughput of requests in
>   concurrent environments.